# StatelessWidget gets rebuilt even though parameters stay the same; notifyListeners() with ChangeNotifier

Tags: flutter, dart, statelesswidget

I've got two StatelessWidgets, one is a child of another. There is also a progress update function which updates the state in the external `TransferState`.
Once `updateProgress` function is being  called the `TransferIndicator` widget gets rebuilt immediately. On the other hand, its parent (`TransfersListTile`) build method isn't called.

It works as expected, however I can't really work out what's the mechanism that's being used here. How Flutter decides to rebuild the: `_TransferIndicator` given that the parameter is a string `hash` that's not being changed, but only used as a lookup ID to reach the `map` in `TransferState` and load the `status` and `progress`.

Documentation: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatelessWidget-class.html says:

> "The build method of a stateless widget is typically only called in
> three situations: the first time the widget is inserted in the tree,
> when the widget's parent changes its configuration, and when an
> InheritedWidget it depends on changes."

If: `notifyListeners();` function is removed, the widget doesn't get rebuilt.

It seem to be closely related to: `ChangeNotifier`, but couldn't find the exact info how it works.

In doc here: https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple#changenotifier there is an example involving `ChangeNotifier`, however doesn't the receiving widget need to be wrapped around: `Consumer` (https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple#consumer)?
In my case there is no `Consumer` wrapping.

```
class TransfersListTile extends StatelessWidget {
  TransfersListTile(this.transfer, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  final Transfer transfer;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      leading: _TransferIndicator(transfer.hash),
      title: Text(transfer.name!),
    );
  }
}

class _TransferIndicator extends StatelessWidget {
  const _TransferIndicator(this.hash, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  final String? hash;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final status = context.select((TransferState s) => s.map[hash]?.status) ?? TransferStatus.pending;
    final progress = context.select((TransferState s) => s.map[hash].progress.percentage);

    return CircularProgressIndicator(
      value: status == TransferStatus.completed ? 100 : (progress / 100),
    );
  }
}
```

function:

```
class TransferState with ChangeNotifier {
  updateProgress(String hash, TransferProgress progress) {
    map[hash]?.progress = progress;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

and provider part:

```
runApp(
      MultiProvider(
        providers: [
          ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => TransferState(),
        ],
        child: MyApp(),
      )
  );
```

Comment: Where is `BuildContext.select()` defined? This does not appear to be a standard method.

Comment: It's part of the `provider` package: https://pub.dev/packages/provider Inside `inherited_provider.dart` there is the `SelectContext` extension on `BuildContext`.
Your comment made me realize that it's actually not a Google package, despite the references here: https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple.
I am going to shop around in the package maintainer docs since it seem to have more examples.

Answer (score 0):

More info about the `select` method and other convenience methods can be found on the `provider` (https://pub.dev/packages/provider) package site.

Excerpt:

> The easiest way to read a value is by using the extension methods on
> [BuildContext]:
>
> - context.watch(), which makes the widget listen to changes on T
> - context.read(), which returns T without listening to it
> - context.select<T, R>(R cb(T value)), which allows a widget to listen    to only a small part of T.